# Insect (I hope) identification

Tags: species-identification

Look, let's get something straight.  I am not the worlds biggest sissy when it comes to bugs, but I'm not David Attenborough either.

Now that that's out of the way, down to business.  Living in Michigan as I do, I was quite surprised to find what looked like the spawn of Predator and a cicada living in my back yard.   Suffice to say it made me nervous.  In one of the pictures below, I have included a cigarette with about 3 drags smoked off of it for sizing.

Please offer insight into the true nature of this animal.

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
[image: img3]

Comment: Looks like a crayfish to me. Did it smell bad? It looks pretty dead, was it in fact dead? Do you live near a river?

Comment: Yes.  Almost certainly dead.  Or very very chill.  I don't live near anything remotely resembling a river.  Where the picture was taken is in an electronics box just under a panel in my yard.  Not deep (10 inches tops).  Box is covered.  This is what I saw when I lifted it.

Comment: How far away is the local water table? if you live in a wettish area it's probably a [prairie crayfish](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/153952/0). They're local to the region, apparently really common, and will live anywhere the dirt is wet. Or damp. (also, have you ever seen a live lobster?)

Comment: I have seen a live lobster.  Not on land though.  I guess I live in a wettish area (it's on a golf course and there is varying terrain), but there is (too my knowledge) no immediate source of water within a couple 100 yards.  In retrospect, it does look like a crayfish; I just was a bit shocked to find one in what I thought of as a relatively dry area.

Comment: Now that I think about it, that may be why it's dead. They're great for the soil, at least.

Comment: This is not insect at any rate )))

Comment: Looks like a scorpion or such, for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of someone more qualified, I believe this to be a prairie crayfish, based on where it was found (land) and what it is (decapod of some kind that looks like a crayfish). Therefore it is unfortunately not an insect.

It's in the right range and roughly the right terrain.

I welcome entomologically qualified advice!

Comment: Yes, definitely a crayfish (Crustacea) and not an insect. Both groups belong to Arthropoda though.

Comment: Well; I guess it's okay that it's not an insect since it's a crayfish.  I was more concerned about it being one of Satans minions. : [